# :Cannot convert value of type 'PFArrayResultBlock'

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfquery

Here is a copy of my code where the error is giving me, the error is on the line where it says `query.findobjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(completionBlock)`.

The full error message is this:

> Cannot convert value of type 'PFArrayResultBlock' (aka'(Optional>, Optional) -> ()') to expected argument type 'PFQueryArrayResultBlock?

I'm totally new to swift.

```
static func getFollowingUsersForUser(user: PFUser, completionBlock: PFArrayResultBlock) {
    let query = PFQuery(className: ParseFollowClass)

    query.whereKey(ParseFollowFromUser, equalTo:user)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(completionBlock)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mismatch between the block types. The expected one is

```
PFQueryArrayResultBlock
```

while the provided one is of type

```
PFArrayResultBlock
```

Note the missing `Query`!?

Comment: @KerbyJean you are welcome. Please accept my answer since it solved your problem by clicking the checkmark in its left. If your question is a short one to answer, sure, go ahead.

Comment: of course, sorry i'm new to the website. Would you mind answering just one last question?. Please!

Comment: @KerbyJean as I said - if it is a short one, yes, if not, I will try to guide you in the correct direction instead,

Comment: Okay thank you again. so here's my problem: Value of type PFObject has no member objectforkey....Code: $0.objectForKey(ParseHelper.ParseFollowToUser) as! PFUser

Comment: ParseHelper.getFollowingUsersForUser(PFUser.currentUser()!) {
            (results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            let relations = results
            self.followingUsers = relations.map {
                $0.objectForKey(ParseHelper.ParseFollowToUser) as! PFUser

Comment: @KerbyJean yes, that is true: you should try `$0[ParseHelper.ParseFollowToUser]` instead. Apart from that - post it as a new question if you really cannot figure it out on your own - it is too much for the comments section.

Comment: Thank you so much but it didn't work. If I post a new question, can I send you the link?

Comment: @KerbyJean I monitor the iOS and related queues closely, I will see your question when posted. Try to be as specific as possible in the question. Post your code properly formatted, the exact error message and what exactly you would expect to happen

Comment: I just posted the question